# Jinja2 code not recognized and displayed correctly

Tags: django, jinja2

I searched all around the web and didn't find an answer so hopefully this is not a duplicate. So I am trying to build a browser app using Django and are using some Jinja code in my html file, but the html file when loaded into a browser doesn't recognize Jinja code and only display raw code. In fact after some experimentation I found out that my browser doesn't display correctly any Jinja code. I checked and I've installed Jinja2 on my computer.

My html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Music FFT Visualizer</title>
    <style></style>
</head>
{% block content %}
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload a Song</button>
    </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
<html>
```

and my view.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import MusicVisualizerForm
from .models import MusicVisualizer


def lastSong(request):
    MusicVisualizers = MusicVisualizer.objects.all()
    MusicVisualizer_last = MusicVisualizers[len(MusicVisualizers)-1]
    return render(request, 'MusicVisualizer/templates/MusicVisualizer.html', { 'MusicVisualizer' : MusicVisualizer_last})


def uploadSong(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = MusicVisualizerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = MusicVisualizerForm()
    return render(request, 'MusicVisualizer/templates/MusicVisualizer.html', {'form' : form})
```

my webpage looks like this:

[image: browser screenshot]

Comment: The browser is not meant to understand jinja code. It only understands html documents. Django's template rendering is supposed to use the jinja template with the context to render html.

Comment: The output you have looks like it would if the template file was served directly from a web server like Apache, bypassing Django. The view code and the template code look ok. How are you serving the web page? Are you using django's runserver command?

Comment: I was not. I tried using that and it worked. Sorry it was such a rookie mistake, I was just starting to learn Django. Thanks a lot!